# How to read in microscope parameters (e.g. defocus, objective lens stigmation) using DM1.85?

Tags: dm-script

I am trying to write a DM script to read and save the microscope parameters (e.g. magnification, defocus, objective lens stigmation, etc.) into a text file. The Digital Micrograph version is 1.85 in our lab. I know it is an old version. I searched in the help file but I did not find any related commands. Can I read in the microscope parameters using such an old version DM?

Answer (score 0):

Hardware script commands are officially supported since GMS 2.3.

However, many of the **EMControl** comands documented therein also existed already during GMS 1.x so you might want to *try and test* them, if they are working.

In case you do not have the HELP documentation, I've done an ASCII dump (copy & paste) of the EMControl reference section and put it on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/pb16zcwv).

*Some* microscopes and *some* GMS versions also copy the information over into the tags of an acquired camera image. (I think some FEI machines used a tag in the "Private" section which was a very long text-string containing all information.)

Comment: You might also want to test the menu xommand `Microscope/Setup` and then the `Test` button. If you don't get proper information there, then the communiction is not sufficient and scripting will not be of help. (Essentially, this UI uses the EMControl commands.)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the "Virtual TEM" package free downloadble from www.temdm.com. Although it is aimed for simulation of TEM in the off-line DM, it consists of a long list of hardware control commands - official and nonofficial. That could be of interest for you. Surely, not all are active in your system but many must work. I tested the commands in inline GMS1.85.